# Self-hosted fonts in Next.js with next-less

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, next.js, font-face

## What I want and what I wonder

I would like to self-host a font (namely Noto) within a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)-application which already makes use of the [@zeit/next-less](https://github.com/vercel/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-less) plugin.

Do I need to use the npm-package [next-fonts](https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts) to self-host fonts? If so, do I need to use the npm-package [next-compose-plugins](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins) to make next-fonts and next-less work together?

Do I need to download the fonts (as WOFF(2)) into the `/public` directory within my applications repository? Or is it also straight-forward to use a npm-package like [fontsource-noto-sans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontsource-noto-sans) which ships those fonts?

## What I tried

I tried to use next-fonts and next-less together, using next-compose-plugins. I created this `/next.config.js`:

```js
const WithPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const WithFonts = require('next-fonts');
const WithLess = require('@zeit/next-less');

module.exports = WithPlugins(
    [
        [ WithFonts, {} ],
        [ WithLess, {} ]
    ],
    {});
```

In my single, global less-file, I put this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Noto Serif'), local('NotoSerif'), url('/public/fonts/noto-serif.woff2') format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-family:
    'Noto Serif',
    // and for debugging:
    monospace;
}
```

I downloaded the font-files for Noto and put them in `…/public/fonts` folder in the Next.js-application's folder.

The Noto font is not loaded and the monospace font keeps being used. Any ideas why? And any ideas how to easily self-host the font with Next.js + next-less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not straight up do a link rel of the font in the document head

I can't see your project but if you have the font in `public` then you should be able to reference externally loaded files

```
<HEAD>
 <link rel="preload" href="/public/fonts/noto-serif.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2">
</HEAD>
```

elsewhere

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

body {
  font-family:
    'Noto Serif',
    // and for debugging:
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works indeed. Could you also tell me the reason why the solution using CSS, `@font-face` and `url(/font/noto-serif.woff2)` does not work?

Comment: It's my guess, its the web pack packaging